# Increase ECS fargate memory using EFS

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

one of my application running ECS(with fargate) needs more memory, the 20GB ephemeral memory is not sufficient for my application, so I am planning to use efs

```
volume {
    name      = "efs-test-space

    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.efs_apache.id
      root_directory = "/"
      transit_encryption      = "ENABLED"
      container_path = "/home/user/efs/"

      authorization_config {
        access_point_id = aws_efs_access_point.efs-access-point.id
        iam             = "ENABLED"
      }
    }
```

I can see it is mounted and my application is able to access the mounted folder, but because of HA and to have parallelism my ecs task count are 6.  Since I am using sone EFS and same will be shared by all tasks. So here the problem I got stuck is providing unique mounted EFS filepath for each task .

I added something like this */home/user/efs/{random_id}* but this I want to make as part of task lifecycle, I mean this folder should get deleted if my task is stopped or destroyed/

So is there a way to mount efs as bind mount or enable delete of folder during task destroy stage?

Answer (score 1):

You can now increase your ephemeral storage size to 200GB all you need to do is to set the ephemeral parameter in fargate task definition

```
"ephemeralStorage": {
    "sizeInGiB": 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While this *could* be achieved in theory, there is a lot of moving parts to it because the life cycle of EFS (and Access Points) is decoupled from the life cycle of tasks. This means you need to create Access Points out of band and on the fly AND these Access Points (and their data) are not automatically deleted when you tear down your tasks. The Fargate/EFS integration did not have this as a primary use case. The primary use case were more around [sharing of the same data among different tasks(which is what you are observing but it doesn't serve your use case!) in addition to provide point persistency for a single task.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/developers-guide-to-using-amazon-efs-with-amazon-ecs-and-aws-fargate-part-1/) .

What you need to solve your problem easily is a [new feature the Fargate team is working on right now and that will allow you to expand your local ephemeral storage as a property of the task](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/384). I can't say more about the timing but the feature is actively being developed so you may want to consider intercepting it rather than building a complex workflow to achieve the same result.